# Prefix and suffix icon not showing without focus. Flutter TextField/Form

Tags: flutter, textfield

In my `TextField`, I can't see `suffix` or `prefix` without focusing on the `TextField`.

```
Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Form(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 8),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                filled: true,
                fillColor: Colors.yellow,
                prefix: Icon(Icons.add),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fM33P.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9aLn.png)

Comment: Could you please [edit] to put the title in English, as well as the question itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, correct the title of your question to English. Remember, this is a community, so the question should be useful and available to everyone.

You want to use the `prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.add)` attribute instead of `prefix`. :)

Comment: thank you I had confused prefix and prefixIcon. I couldn't tell the difference.

Comment: You welcome. Is a detail that easily goes unnoticed. Even I didn't knew it. But I did knew that this extensible used widgets are pretty robust and modular in terms of usability, so just looking into attributes will show us how we should use it and solve the problem. Besides, analizing it improves our knowledge. Higly recommended!
Take care :)